# How can I convert rows with three columns into SQL insert statements?

Tags: excel

I have a spreadsheet looking like this:

```
    あう  to meet
青   あお  blue
青い  あおい blue
```

Is there a way that I could convert the data in these columns into three SQL statements that I could then use to enter the data into a database?  I am not so much concerned in asking how to form the statement but I would like to know if there's a way I can take data in columns and make it into a script?

If I could convert this into:

col1: 青い  col2: あおい  col3: blue

I could add and modify this for the correct format

```
INSERT INTO JLPT col1,col2,col3 VALUES ('青い', 'あおい', 'blue')
etc
```

Comment: What database are you using?  What is the table structure, etc.?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen - I am using SQL Server but it's more of a general statement on the Excel side so getting any data at all into a file with some additional text would be a good enough start for me.

Comment: You could save your worksheet as CSV and try to import it into SQL Server.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen - One problem there is that sometimes the third column contains two words and a comma

Answer (score 0):

Use the formula

```
="('"&A1&"', '"&B1&"', '"&C1&"'), "
```

in column D and copy the formula down for all the rows. Then prepend

```
Insert into JPT (col1, col2, col3) values
```

and your are done. The end result will be something like this:

[image]

<sub>Just don't forget to delete the last comma (and optionally exchange it for a semicolon) when you copy over the data from Excel.</sub>