# I need to insert data into SQL server from Excel using VBA

Tags: sql-server, vba, excel

I need to insert `test-vba.xlsx` data into SQL server to the particular database

```
Sub insertion()
    Dim conn As ADODB.Connection
    Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim sConnString As String
    Dim rsstring As String
    Dim m, nrows As Integer

    Set wkb = Workbooks("test-vba.xlsx").Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate
    sConnString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=PRATEEP-PC\SQLEXPRESS;" & _
                  "Initial Catalog=PPDS_07Dec_V1_Decomposition;" & _
                  "Integrated Security=SSPI;"
    Set conn = New ADODB.Connection
    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
    conn.Open sConnString

    For m = 0 To nrows - 1
```

Comment: Is this code working? Is there a specific problem? If yes, describe the problem (what, where, how) and what your code should do instead.

Comment: Please read [ask]. You even didn't ask a question. Describe your issue well, what is working already, what is not working, what do you expect. Also see [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)

Comment: Here is the code [to import a CSV file into an SQL DB](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26743347/faster-way-to-import-excel-spreadsheet-to-array-with-ado/30346959#30346959). You can easily tweak the code to fit your needs. If you want to import that Excel file only one time then the following solution might be easier / faster: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39182049/how-can-i-convert-rows-with-three-columns-into-sql-insert-statements/39189289#39189289

Answer (score 1):

Here are a couple ideas.

```vb
Sub UpdateTable()

    Dim cnn As Object
    Dim wbkOpen As Workbook
    Dim objfl As Variant
    Dim rngName As Range
    Workbooks.Open "C:\Users\Excel\Desktop\Excel_to_SQL_Server.xls"
    Set wbkOpen = ActiveWorkbook
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    Set rngName = Range(Range("A1"), Range("A1").End(xlToLeft).End(xlDown))
    rngName.Name = "TempRange"
    strFileName = wbkOpen.FullName
    Set cnn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    cnn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & strFileName & ";Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=Yes"";"
    nSQL = "INSERT INTO [odbc;Driver={SQL Server};Server=Server_Name;Database=[Database_Name].[dbo].[TBL]]"
    nJOIN = " SELECT * from [TempRange]"
    cnn.Execute nSQL & nJOIN
    MsgBox "Uploaded Successfully"
    wbkOpen.Close
    Set wbkOpen = Nothing
    
End Sub

Sub InsertInto()

'Declare some variables
Dim cnn As adodb.Connection
Dim cmd As adodb.Command
Dim strSQL As String

'Create a new Connection object
Set cnn = New adodb.Connection

'Set the connection string
cnn.ConnectionString = "Server_Name;Database=Database_Name;Trusted_Connection=True;"

'Create a new Command object
Set cmd = New adodb.Command

'Open the connection
cnn.Open
'Associate the command with the connection
cmd.ActiveConnection = cnn

'Tell the Command we are giving it a bit of SQL to run, not a stored procedure
cmd.CommandType = adCmdText

'Create the SQL
strSQL = "UPDATE TBL SET JOIN_DT = 2013-01-13 WHERE EMPID = 2"

'Pass the SQL to the Command object
cmd.CommandText = strSQL

'Open the Connection to the database
cnn.Open

'Execute the bit of SQL to update the database
cmd.Execute

'Close the connection again
cnn.Close

'Remove the objects
Set cmd = Nothing
Set cnn = Nothing

End Sub
```

Here is another idea.

```vb
Sub Button_Click()
'TRUSTED CONNECTION
    On Error GoTo errH
   
    Dim con As New ADODB.Connection
    Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset
    Dim strPath As String
    Dim intImportRow As Integer
    Dim strFirstName, strLastName As String
   
    Dim server, username, password, table, database As String
   
   
    With Sheets("Sheet1")
           
            server = .TextBox1.Text
            table = .TextBox4.Text
            database = .TextBox5.Text
           
           
            If con.State <> 1 Then
       
                con.Open "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=" & server & ";Initial Catalog=" & database & ";Integrated Security=SSPI;"
                'con.Open
       
            End If
            'this is the TRUSTED connection string
           
            Set rs.ActiveConnection = con
           
            'delete all records first if checkbox checked
            If .CheckBox1 Then
                con.Execute "delete from tbl_demo"
            End If
       
            'set first row with records to import
            'you could also just loop thru a range if you want.
            intImportRow = 10
           
            Do Until .Cells(intImportRow, 1) = ""
                strFirstName = .Cells(intImportRow, 1)
                strLastName = .Cells(intImportRow, 2)
               
                'insert row into database
                con.Execute "insert into tbl_demo (firstname, lastname) values ('" & strFirstName & "', '" & strLastName & "')"
               
                intImportRow = intImportRow + 1
            Loop
           
            MsgBox "Done importing", vbInformation
           
            con.Close
            Set con = Nothing
   
    End With
   
Exit Sub

errH:
    MsgBox Err.Description
End Sub
```

Also, check out the links below.

http://www.cnblogs.com/anorthwolf/archive/2012/04/25/2470250.html

http://www.excel-sql-server.com/excel-sql-server-import-export-using-vba.htm